# MiKTeX isn't updating psfonts.map

Tags: fonts, miktex, miktex-update, map

Haven't found answer neither internet not here so going to ask. I'm using latest `MiKTeX 23.10.12` with all updates.

[image]

Also I want to use third party fonts with `pdflatex`. I have all needed font and auxiliary files which I placed in needed folders.

The issue is MiKTeX doesn't want to update `psfonts.map` file through `Map *.map` line in config file. So I had to edit `psfonts.map`  manualy for propper work contrary to warning. All accessible tools such as `Refresh font map files` in MiKTeX console or `initexmf --mkmaps` doesn't work.

It works for me but it will work until first upgrade. Is MiKTeX able to work with `.map` file more proper or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: pdflatex doesn't use psfonts.map but pdftex.map normally. What did you do to change that?

Comment: I'm using ```pdflatex``` to typeset my document. I have to edit ```psfonts.map``` manually to be able typeset with third party fonts. In other case I have error like this: ```!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file rjcsr8t): Font rjcsr8t at 420 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!```. And I never tried to change ```pdftex.map``` file.

Comment: make a small hello-world document (without any third party fonts), compile with pdflatex and then show the complete log-file.

Comment: Something happened that I can't explain. For MWE I edited ```psfonts.map``` to it initial state assuming that I won't be able typset document with third paty font but I made it. Any errors that I have been seen before didn't appear. I got correct .pdf file with third party font. Then I figured out there are two files ```psfonts.map``` in my MiKTeX. ```C:\Users\user9\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config\psfonts.map``` and ```C:\Users\user9\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\map\dvips\psfonts.map```. They differ. The second one contain information about third party font.

Comment: The same up to ```pdftex.map```. There are two of them and they differ. The second one contain information about third party font. It seems to I don't know about MiKTeX file structure and how it works.

Comment: the location in dvips/config is outdated. Nowadays map files should be in fonts\map. But you shouldn't edit the files in miktex main texmf tree manually. Use a local updmap.cfg to append new maps. See https://docs.miktex.org/manual/advanced.html#psfonts

Comment: I used a local updmap.cfg to append new maps and it obviously changed ```...\fonts\map\dvips\psfonts.map``` but in some reason typesetting didn't work. So I tried to change ```...\devips\config\psfonts.map``` manually cause local updmap.cfg wasn't affecting to it content. I don't know why but It helped. I restored all my manual changes and luckily errors didn't came back as it had came back this morning. Thanx for help! It works for now I hope it'll work a while.

Answer (score 0):

So I have some thoughts about described issue. First of all I use an ancient version of MiKTeX that was updated more than one times. MiKTeX proceeds make changes to itself file structure so I already have tremendously creepy mix with same name files in separate folders that differ.

What files are using to typesetting and what files changed while config procedure only MiKTeX knowing. So I guess the better way to deal with it to delete old franken-MiKTeX and install new with clear structure.